# .NET MVC Linq -> XML RSS reader : Twitter XML Parsing Error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, xml, linq-to-xml

It seems like no matter what I do, I cannt get my twitter RSS feed to show up on my view. I'm not getting any errors, and the RSS feed loads correctly, I just can't grab the Model's information...

Here's my ViewModel

```
namespace MvcMusicStore.ViewModels
{
    public class HomeRssFeedViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<TwitterPosts> Tweets { get; set; }

        public HomeRssFeedViewModel()
        {
            Tweets = GetPosts();
        }

        public IEnumerable<TwitterPosts> GetPosts()
        {
            var xmlTreeTwitter = XDocument.Load("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/...");
            XNamespace xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";

            return from item in xmlTreeTwitter.Descendants(xmlns + "item")
                   select new TwitterPosts
                   {
                       pubDate = item.Element(xmlns + "pubDate").Value,
                       Title = item.Element(xmlns + "Title").Value,
                       Link = item.Element(xmlns + "link").Value
                   };
        }
        public class TwitterPosts
        {
            public string pubDate { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Link { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new HomeRssFeedViewModel();
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Here's my View:

```
%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcMusicStore.ViewModels.HomeRssFeedViewModel>" %>

...
        <div class="rss">
           <% foreach(var tweet in Model.Tweets)
               {%>
                    <b><%: tweet.Title %></b>
              <% } %>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your LINQ query is the problem. The following will work:

```
        public IEnumerable<TwitterPosts> GetPosts()
        {
            var xmlTreeTwitter = XDocument.Load("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/#####.rss");

            var v = from item in xmlTreeTwitter.Descendants("rss").Elements("channel").Elements("item")
                   select new TwitterPosts
                   {
                       pubDate = item.Element("pubDate").Value,
                       Title = item.Element("title").Value,
                       Link = item.Element("link").Value
                   };

            return v;
        }
        public class TwitterPosts
        {
            public string pubDate { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Link { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the problem is in your XML parsing. You correctly load the tweets but the `xmlTreeTwitter.Descendants` function doesn't return anything and finally your `model.Tweets.Count()` equals to `0` which is the reason you are not getting any output in the view. Make sure you are using the correct namespace and proper selectors to parse the XML response.